# Django ORM create model object using another object

Tags: python, django, orm

How can we create a model record or object using another object.

`get_object = my_model.objects.filter(id=1)`

I want to do something like below to create object in another database

`my_model.objects.using('DB2').create(my_model=get_object)`

Comment: Override the `save()` method in your model?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can get yours model as dict and unpack it to new model object.

```
from users.models import User, AnotherUser
from django.forms.models import model_to_dict

old_user = User.objects.get(pk=1)
data = model_to_dict(old_user, fields=['username', 'email'])

new_user = AnotherUser.objects.using('DB2').create(**data)
```

Its better to not copy pk(id) but provide this to database by itself

Answer (score 0):

You can overide [save](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/4.1/topics/db/models/#overriding-model-methods) method or use [django signals](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/4.1/topics/signals/), based on your requirements.

You can use the code below to replicate the object to the model in another database having same fields.

```
get_object = my_model.objects.filter(id=1).values().first()
get_object.update({'id': None})
my_model.objects.using('DB2').create(**get_object)
```